# Class expected error and problems with my for loop in a code for computing N prime numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that will output N (N being the argument) prime
numbers (one number per line). I had my code working, but I realized that it
wasn't giving me N prime numbers, it was giving me the numbers that were prime
within N. So if I put in 10 for my argument, it wouldn't give me the first ten
prime numbers, it'd give me 2,3,5,6,7,9.

Then, I noticed that 6 and 9 aren't prime numbers. So I tried fixing my for
loop, but I could only get rid of the 6.

I'm trying to mess around with my program, but I can't seem to figure out how to

1. output the first N prime numbers, not prime numbers in the range of N, and
2. fix the loop so that it only includes primes.

My current idea is to try redefining N, but then I get the error message
"'.class' expected" for the line where I write `N=boolean class Prime`. I believe
I may have to use an array for this program, but I'm really new to java, and
this is getting pretty difficult for me.

```
public class Prime{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        int N;

        try{
            N=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Please enter only valid integers.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        if(N<=0){
            System.out.println("N must be a positive integer larger than 0.");
            return;
        }

        N=boolean class Prime;

        for(int i=2; i<N; i++){

            boolean Prime=true;

            for (int j=2; j<i; j++) {

                if (i%j==0) {
                    Prime=false;
                }
                break;

            }           

            if (Prime) {
                System.out.println(i+" ");
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to put the **break** inside the **braces**:

```
if (i%j==0) {
    Prime=false;
    break;
}
```

Otherwise you'll **exit** after the first check `(i % j == 0)` and you'll not check all the `j` values.

Comment: Thank you!! It complied after I followed your suggestion.

Comment: *edit: I meant that AFTER it compiled, this fix got rid of all the non-prime results. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code I wrote some time ago to do what you want. See if you can figure out where you are wrong from this:

```
import java.util.*;

class PrimeTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = -1;

        while(test != 0){
        System.out.println("Write number to check if prime: (exit with 0)");
        test = sc.nextInt();
        boolean b;

        Test t = new Test();
        b = t.isPrime(test);

        if(b)
            System.out.println("Prime");
        if(!b)
            System.out.println("Not prime");
        }
    }

}

class Test{
    boolean isPrime(int n){
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
                if(n%i == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
if (i%j==0) 
{
  Prime=false;
}
break;
```

Look at what it's doing. It doesn't look at whether it is false or not. It just simply breaks out of the loop. You have to break `if` the condition is true - so put the break statement **INSIDE** the `if` statement.

```
if(i%j == 0)
{
  Prime = false;
  break;
}
```